# How can I connect to an RDS PostgreSQL database using Powershell in a Lambda function?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, powershell, aws-lambda

We are trying to write a powershell script that can read data from an Aurora PostgreSQL cluster.  We want to do this from within the Lambda dotnetcore3.1 environment.  I don't see any documentation anywhere in google space that gives any pointers on what program/cmdlet/module could be used.  In Windows, we can use an ODBC driver and/or psql.  However, neither of these seem to exist in the Lambda ecosystem.

Has anyone successfully made a connection to PostgreSQL in Lambda using powershell?  If so, what did you use to do it?

Comment: [This](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/powershell-package.html) is what you need. Kindly check the PS package deployment

Comment: @RanadipDutta  In the Lamba environment, I don't have access to install software.  I don't have an issue connecting from a server I control, I just need to know if Lambda actually has something installed so that I can make the connection.  When we do this from c#, we deploy the .dll's with the application, I don't see any neat package that I can deploy with my powershell scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I reckon the core question is how to get your Lambda function access to the RDS PostgreSQL instance, which I can think of 2 approaches:

1. Use AWS Secretes Manager to securely database username and password, retrieve them via AWS SDK during Lambda execution: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-securely-provide-database-credentials-to-lambda-functions-by-using-aws-secrets-manager/
2. Use RDS IAM Authentication to grant Lambda function access to RDS: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/iam-role-based-authentication-to-amazon-aurora-from-serverless-applications/

Personally I'd recommend approach #2, though in the past I only used approach #1.

Comment: I don't have any issue authenticating if I can make a connection.  I can't find a way to make a connection to try and authenticate.

Comment: don't know much about C#, did you read Lambda C# runtime doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-csharp.html? I used other programming languages such as Javascript and Go, normally I'd package the dependencies as part of the Lambda function

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to this when running powershell on windows.  It takes a bit of unpacking, but here are the steps:
Start at the [npgsql home page](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/index.html).  From there, there is a [link to the NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql/). On the NuGet page use the download link to get the package (e.g. npgsql.7.0.4.nupkg).
Once you have downloaded the package, rename it with a .zip extension, open it and navigate to the correct lib subfolder (e.g. net6.0).
Copy out the npgsql.dll file to somewhere you remember and can access (e.g. c:\temp).

Similarly, find the [Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions/).  Download the package and copy out the appropriate .dll file.

In powershell, Add-Type the two .dll files.  e.g.

```
Add-Type -Path c:\temp\npgsql.dll
Add-Type -Path c:\temp\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll
```

Those files are enough to enable this example to run.  It is possible that other nuget packages must be unpacked to get all the types to work.

```
add-type -path c:\temp\npgsql.dll
add-type -path c:\temp\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll
$db = [npgsql.npgsqlConnection]::new()
$db.ConnectionString = 'Host=postgre.server; Database=Example; Username=postgre; Password=Example'
$query = $db.CreateCommand()
$query.CommandText = 'select count(*) from public.example'
$cursor = $query.ExecuteReader()
$cursor.Read()
$count = $cursor.GetInt32(0)
$cursor.dispose()
$db.dispose()
```